# Error found when loading /etc/profile at start of the laptop

Tags: 20.04, error-handling

[code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If8gC.jpg)

Error found when loading /etc/profile:
/etc/profile: line 28: Directory: No such file or directory

As a result the session will not be configured correctly. You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.

I am new with Ubuntu; i use version 20.04.2 LTS focal. Every time i start new my laptop i receive this error message. Line 28 from where is the error? How can i fix it?

Comment: What are the content of your `/etc/profile` ? Especially around line 28 there should be a reference to "Directory" that is wrong in the context.

Comment: how can i see the content? When i type /etc/profile it tells me "Permission denied"

Comment: Try `cat -n /etc/profile` or `less -N /etc/profile`

Comment: i have this code block inside JAVA_HOME=<Directory where JAVA has been extracted>/jdk1.8.0
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH

Comment: That's a line that you (or some software that you installed) has added - and `<Directory where JAVA has been extracted>` is a placeholder that should have been replaced by an actual directory path.